# WPF - Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, parent-child, wpfdatagrid

I'm getting a LOT of binding errors in which they all have in common that the binding is something like:

```
   Text="{Binding MiddleParent.Child}"
```

The errors are saying that the `dataitem` is null, however my application runs find and the data is there besides the slow performance bc of all the binding error logging going on. This is all happening inside of a `datagrid`. So for example if my data grid's itemsource is a collection of (`MainParent`) and inside the `datagridcolumn` I bind `DisplayMemberBinding` to: `Car.FullName`, then in output I get all kind of binding errors. Is this due to lazy loading? How can I fix this. So basically the binding is `User.Car.FullName`. An example setup is as follows:

```
 <datagrid itemsSource="{Binding Users}">
      <datagrid.columns>
         <DataGridColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Car.FullName}" //Throws binding error
         <DataGridColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" //Does NOT Throw binding error
      </datagrid.columns>
 </datagrid>



  System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead.
```

I have tried setting `Fallbackvalue` and `TargetNullValue` and both do not work.
NOTE: Once app is all loaded, datagrid IS showing the value for Car.FullName, weird I know.

Comment: I guess it happens when Car is null.

Comment: Thats whats weird, car is never null.

Comment: Have you tested it with lazy loading disabled ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't disable lazy loading without messing up the app, I'am also dealing with a lot of data as well.

Comment: Lets give it a try. You could try to apply DataContext before window InitializeComponent(). However, I am not sure if it will cause other issue.

Comment: See what I can do, Have already tried setting DataContext before InitializeComponent, didn't work though

Comment: Did you try providing a fallback value?

Answer (score 0):

Is this not a standard WPF datagrid?

I don't recognize that column type. I would expect something like this:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=OneWay}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Car.FullName, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: It's actually a Telerik GridView I'm using, same thing pretty much as a datagrid, but yes as far as syntax goes your right